# jquery on does not work but live does using 1.7.1 library

Tags: jquery, events

i have a button that is created dynamically so i need to use .live on my code.  Here's an example:

```
$('#send').live('click', function(){
.....
..... code .....
.....
});
```

I'm using jQuery library 1.7.1 and i wanted to change it to using .on but it does not work. Why is this? Is the syntax different?

I looked at the documentation and I dont seem to be doing anything wrong. I dont mind leaving it like live but i would like to know if I'm doing something wrong.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Do you get an error? What happens? You might want to post your real code. You can also use Fiddler to see if you are getting any download problems.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Is the syntax different? Yes. Did you read all of the `.on()` doco page you linked to?

The following summary about how to switch from `.live()` to `.delegate()` or `.on()` is from the [`.live()` doco page](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

So in your case you want:

```
$(document).on('click', '#send', function(){
   // your code here
});
```

Note though that ideally you won't be using `$(document)`, you'll be using `$(someotherelement)` to attach the handler to an element closer to your '#send' element. If you can, use whatever the direct parent element of '#send' is, or if the parent is dynamically created too use *its* parent.

Comment: And the really great thing about `.on()` (or `.delegate()`) is that you can change `document` to any `<root element>` you want.

Comment: yeah i just didn't understand that you had to use two selectors like Slaks

Comment: for example if its inside a form it coud be like     $('$customForm').on('click', '#send', function(){})?

Comment: @Jasper - yep, I was just adding a note about that. @Samual Lopez - yes, that's it exactly. Well, almost: you probably meant `$('#customForm')` (note the '#').

Comment: Yes, the element in the first selector must exist at the time that the event handler is attached, so if your form has not been created yet you can use `document`. (Or if the form will be a child of some other element that does exist you could use that other element.)

Comment: That clears things up. I was delegating from a dynamically created element as well and that wasn't working. Changed that now.

Comment: Since `on()` can not be used to select the intended element directly, like `live()` can, why is `live()` depreciated... that is the more preferred method of coding in my opinion...

Comment: @SerjSagan - `.live()` doesn't really select the element directly, it still attaches the actual event handler at the document level. Yes, with `.live()` you put your selector in `$()` rather than passing it as a parameter to `live()`, but in fact that's a reason why `.live()` is worse: it means you created a jQuery object that has to search for elements matching your selector that then doesn't get used because `.live()` only needs the selector itself. That is to say that it does what `.on()` does but with more steps behind the scenes so it is less efficient.

Comment: @SerjSagan - P.S. And unlike `.on()` or `.delegate()`, the `.live()` method doesn't provide an option to specify a parent closer to the element than `document`.

Answer (score 6):

To use event delegation, `.on` requires *two* selectors, like `.delegate`.

```
$('some container').on('click', '#send', function() { ... });
```